# Add Share and Open in Safari options to answer menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

When you tap on the question menu, you get a list of options that includes Share and Open in Safari:

[image: question menu]

The answer menu just gives you the Edit option, which isn't quite as useful. Could the Share and Open in Safari options be added to the answer menu as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had started on this last week then did something else instead.  It'll be in the next build.

Comment: Heh, I went to accept this from the app and found out I couldn't. Hopefully that's on the todo list too :)