# Where did the phrase "open in" [Safari] go?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, ios-app, wording

<sup>This really might be a minor issue, but since there's a tag [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) for that, I thought I bring it up.</sup>

When you click "… More" on a question in the app on iOS it brings up the dialog shown below. The link "Safari" will not take you on a cool journey to see wildlife but rather will open another app. Therefor it would be great if the wording could be changed to:

> Open in Safari

[image: More dialog in iOS app]

I found this question "[Add Share and Open in Safari options to answer menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220375/190341)". In the screenshot it seems that the wording "Open in Safari" actually was used earlier.

Comment: 'The link "Safari" will not take you on a cool journey to see wildlife but rather will open another app' - lol, +1 :D

Comment: Yes, a little confusing indeed.

Comment: Actually, I'm guessing it may be something with iOS. Do you have any other "browsers" installed? Does tapping it lead you to a menu of options?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yes, I do: Chrome is installed, too. But there's no option for your default browser on iOS. Also by default there's no list of options in which browser you can open a link. iOS is different to Android that way. ;)

Comment: This happened because we added a toolbar and wanted all the titles to be one word long in the toolbar.  It makes more sense when you just see "Safari" with a leaving-the-app-looking icon.  We should really have separate titles for the action sheet vs the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.